# Taking a sum of exponentials and turning it into a fraction

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I'm curious as to how they made this jump in logic:

$$A e^{i \omega t} \left[1 + e^{i \phi} + e^{2i\phi} + \dots + e^{(N-1)i\phi}\right] = A e^{i\omega t} \frac{e^{i N\phi} - 1}{e^{i\phi} - 1}$$

How did they convert the sum within the brackets into the expression below?

Answer (score 2):

They used:
 1. Power laws: $(e^x)^a=e^{xa}$
 2. The sum of a geometric series

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$\sum_{k=m}^n r^k=\frac{r^m-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

is the sum of a geometric series.

Let $m=0$, $n=N-1$ and $r=e^{i\phi}$.  Then, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{i\phi}=\frac{1-e^{iN\phi}}{1-e^{i\phi}}=\frac{e^{iN\phi}-1}{e^{i\phi}-1}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{-a}{-b}$